# string handling in c and C++ mix programming

Tags: c++, string

I want to use an API from a library. I am confused about its second argument.

```
    cs_disasm(handle,(const uint8_t*)("\xff\x43\x12\xd1"),4 , 0x0, 1, &insn);
```

The above code works fine. "\xff\x43\x12\xd1", this string represents a machine code. I want this API to accept arbitrary machine code. What I have now is an

```
uint32_t machine_code. I use it as follow, but not work.
std::stringstream ss;
ss<< std::hex  << setfill('0') << setw(2) <<  (int)(machine_code&0xff); // int decimal_value
std::string res1 ( ss.str() );
ss.str(std::string());
//cout << res1 << endl;

ss<< std::hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << (int)((machine_code>>8)&0xff); // int decimal_value
std::string res2 ( ss.str() );
ss.str(std::string());


ss<< std::hex << setfill('0') << setw(2)  << (int)((machine_code>>16)&0xff); // int decimal_value
std::string res3 ( ss.str() );
ss.str(std::string());

ss<< std::hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << (int)((machine_code>>24)&0xff); // int decimal_value
std::string res4 ( ss.str() );
string modified_machine_code = "\\x"+ res1 +"\\x"+  res2 +"\\x"+ res3 +"\\x"+ res4;
cs_disasm(hao_handle,(const uint8_t*)(modified_machine_code.c_str()),4 , 0x0, 1, &hao_insn);
```

What is the problem with my code? If you have a better solution, that is also great.

Comment: **C is not C++ is not C!** Do not add tags just because they use the same letter(s)!

Comment: The API is used for C, but I have to use the API in my c++ code. That is what I meant.

Comment: It does not compile in C and does not even use C-syntax (let away the semantics).

Comment: This API is designed for C and the problem might have something to do with the compatibility, although it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is deceiving you: `"\xff\x43\x12\xd1"` has only 4 characters (well, plus the ending NUL, but you don't need that) You seem to think that it has 16 characters, with all the `\` and the `x` and so, but that's only the way raw bytes are written inside a string literal.

What you really want is an array of bytes, but since in C++ string literals are arrays of `char` and `char` is a byte, hence your confusion.

Your original string could be written clearer this way:

```
uint8_t code[] = { 0xff, 0x43, 0x12, 0xd1 };
```

Now, to the question. You have a `int32_t` and you want to convert it to an array of `int8_t`. That can be done in three ways: little-endian, big-endian, or native-endian (that will be equal to one of the other, but which one depends on the architecture). Which one you want to use will depend on where do you get that `int32_t` from.

For native-endian it is easy, you can cast the pointers:

```
const uint8_t *code = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t *>(&machine_code);
```

For little-endian and big-endian, you are better building a new array:

```
const uint8_t code_le[] = {
    machine_code & 0xFF,
    (machine_code >> 8) & 0xFF,
    (machine_code >> 16) & 0xFF,
    (machine_code >> 24) & 0xFF,
};
const uint8_t code_be[] = {
    (machine_code >> 24) & 0xFF,
    (machine_code >> 16) & 0xFF,
    (machine_code >> 8) & 0xFF,
    machine_code & 0xFF,
};
```

There is no need to invoke the `stringstream` classes at all.

Comment: You r awesome. You help me a lot. :)

Comment: Just a bit nit-picky: `char` is a `byte`, but not necessarily 8 bits as `uint8_t` is guaranteed to be. (OTOH, if `char` is not 8 bits, there cannot be a `uint8_t`, as `char` is required to be at least 8 bits and the smallest type available)

Comment: yeah. The truth is that I misunderstood the meaning of "\xff\x43\x12\xd1". "\x" has a special meaning in a string literal.